# How to separate self-defining values from sigma?

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_kx_j^{b_k+b_i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_jx_j^{b_i}$$

What I need to do is solve $a$ for every $i$ given ($i$ is between 1 and $m$), so their result won't be composed of any other $a_i$. (They can contain any $b$ $x$ $y$.)

I am currently stuck here:
$$a_i = \frac{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_jx_j^{b_i} - \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} a_k\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j^{b_k+b_i} - \sum_{k=i+1}^{m} a_k\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j^{b_k+b_i} }{\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j^{b_i+b_i}}$$
Notice that $a_i$ equal to expression(?) that contains any $a$ (Find $a_k$) except $a_i$, that means that it's indirectly containing itself. Can I get a hint?

I thought of somehow folding out only $- \sum_{k=i+1}^{m} a_k\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j^{b_k+b_i}$ to something that doesn't contain any $a$, and then it's easily solvable from here, but how to start?

Comment: By the way, is the first equation has a name?

Comment: i don't think that it is possible to solve this, unless you make further assumptions (e.g. $x$ is a not a variable, but a symbol for polynomial).

Comment: You have 1 linear equation and $m$ unknowns, which yields an (infinite) set of solutions, which are spanned but at least $m-1$ linearly independent basic solutions.

Comment: @will I thought it should yield $!n$ solutions there is $m$ numbers and then you put them however you want in $a$. I am quiet aware of multiple solutions. (Infinitely sounds a bit too much I think.)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky Unless you have additional constraints, such as insisting a fixed solution of $\{a_i\}_{1\ldots m}$ holds for many values of $x_j$, or that each $0 < a_i$, or some other relationship between the $a$ and $b,x,$ or $y$, then linear algebra can explicitly give you unlimited solutions. By the way, are you trying to find the coefficents of some sparse polynomials?

Comment: @will Wait, but I have M equations and M variables, why should it be a problem? And yes I am trying to find the variables for $$y_j = a_1x_j^{b_1}+a_2x_j^{b_2}...$$ ($a$ and $b$) to make the equation closest (possible, not 0 close) to every variable $y$ for $x$. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: In the simplest possible case, $m=n=a_1=y_1=1$, your equation is $x_1^{b_1 + b_i} = x_1^{b_i}$.  If $b_1 \neq 0$, how is this ever solvable?

Comment: @EricTowers Nope, the only thing that will add in the sigma when $m = 1$ is $a_1x_j^{b_1+b_i}$ (running $j$ from $1$ to $n$...), but $b_i$ can be only $b_1$ so it will be $a_1x_j^{b_i+b_i}$ which is $a_1x_j^{2b_i}$. I think you interchanged $i$ and $j$ in my equation.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky : Exactly.  No possibility of solution (unless $b_1=0$).  Note also that I set $a_1=y_1=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sigma notation is somewhat confusing. From the comments, you seem to be looking for a linear combination of $M$ powers, $a_1x^{b_1}+\ldots+a_Mx^{b_M}$, that is "closest" to $N$ points, $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_N,y_N).$
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{lllll}
x_1^{b_1} & \ldots & x_1^{b_k} & \ldots & x_1^{b_M} \\
\vdots    & & & & \vdots \\
x_j^{b_1} & \ldots & x_j^{b_k} & \ldots & x_j^{b_M} \\
\vdots    & & & & \vdots \\
x_N^{b_1} & \ldots & x_N^{b_k} & \ldots & x_N^{b_M} 
\end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{l}
a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_k \\ \vdots \\ a_M
\end{array} \right]\  \approx\  \left[\begin{array}{l}
y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_j \\ \vdots \\ y_N
\end{array} \right]
$$
We can call the $N\times M$ matrix of powers $\mathbf{B};\  $ call the vector of $N$ unknowns $\mathbf{a}\  $ and the $M$ y values we are trying to approximate $\mathbf{y}.\  $ For example, row $j$ of $\mathbf{Ba}\approx\mathbf{y}$ is $\  y_j \approx a_1x_j^{b_1} + \ldots + a_kx_j^{b_K} + \ldots + a_Mx_j^{b_M}.\  $ If we take $\approx$ as a goal to minimize the $\ell_2$ distance from $\mathbf{Ba}$ to $\mathbf{y}$, then the [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem) solution is given by:
$$
0 < |\mathbf{B^TB}| \implies\  \mathbf{a} = 
\left(\mathbf{B^TB}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B^Ty}
$$
There are (many) "solutions" for $\mathbf{a}$ when the determinant, $|\mathbf{B^TB}|,$ is 0. We can avoid this difficulty by removing redundant collumns from $\mathbf{B}$ and providing enough points, $M\le N.\  $ Notice that when $N=M$, our solution reduces to an exact "approximation", $\  \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{B^{-1}y}.$

Computing the least squares regression in practice might use orthogonal projections for better numerical stability, while we used the so called "normal" equations. Some sort of least square, aka linear regression, support is provided in every major math toolkit.

Comment: Sorry for not telling (Didn't thought of it causing a problem in answering?), but it's always $2m<n$, and I am even thinking of making it $n = 100000$ and $m = 10$, which makes it a problem to remove from $n$. (I might had the wrong impression of the answer?)

Comment: I had small mistake near the end of my answer. The correct way to avoid $|\mathbf{B^TB}| = 0$ is to make sure the collumns of $\mathbf{B}$ are linear independent. When $\mathbf{B}$ has $n=100000$ rows in $m=10$ collumns, you almost certainly will have $0 < |\mathbf{B^TB}|$ and an "easy" to compute solution: $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{(B^TB)^{-1}B^Ty}$

Comment: Oh, I got it. That's an additional to my question (if you think it's easy to answer that then you may try), what I don't have B? I actually need to calculate the whole thing.